# Name error on last line (it says p not defined)

Tags: python

Here is the code

```
#
# start.py
# @author Merubokkusu
# @created Fri Jan 04 2019 00:58:07 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
# @copyright 2018 - 2019
# @license CC BY-NC-ND 3.0 US | https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/us/
# @website https://github.com/Merubokkusu/discord-spam-bots/
# @email liam@merubokkusu.com
# @last-modified Tue Mar 05 2019 02:11:47 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
#

import sys
import subprocess
import os
from time import sleep
from config import *

proxy_number = 0
spam_text = None

if os.path.exists('tokens.txt'):
    userToken = open("tokens.txt").read().splitlines()
    w1 = "EDIT YOUR CONFIG.PY BEFORE USING!\n-=Using tokens.txt=-\n"
else:
    w1 = "EDIT YOUR CONFIG.PY BEFORE USING!\n"

if os.path.exists('proxies.txt'):
    proxy_list = open("proxies.txt").read().splitlines()
else:
    proxy_list = []
    for token in userToken:
        proxy_list.append('localhost')

if os.path.exists('combolist.txt'):
    emailList = open("combolist.txt").read().splitlines()
if os.path.exists('token_gen.txt'):
    tokenV = open("token_gen.txt").read().splitlines()

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    for char in w1:
        sleep(0.01)
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(0.5)
    print("Type one of the following numbers to launch that spammmer")
    print("       +========-Server Spammers-=========+")
    print("1 : Text Spammer - Write your own text to spam")
    print("2 : Image Spammer - Spam random images in a selected folder")
    print("3 : Insult Spammer - Picks insults online and spams them")
    print("         +========-DM Spammers-=========+      ")
    print("4 : Text Spammer - Write your own text to spam")
    print("5 : Image Spammer - Spam random images in a selected folder")
    print("6 : Insult Spammer - Picks insults online and spams them")
    print("           +========-Other-=========+")
    print("7 : Join Server - Join the server thats written in the config")
    print("           +========-Account Creator-=========+")
    print("8 : Account creator - Create bulk accounts")
    print("9 : Account verifier - Verify accounts")

    in_pick = float(input("Select a bot: "))
else:
    in_pick = float(sys.argv[1])
    spam_text = sys.argv[2]


if in_pick == 1:
    if os.path.exists('text.txt'):
        for token in userToken:
            p = subprocess.Popen([pythonCommand,'bots/server/discord_text_spam.py',token,'null',proxy_list[proxy_number]])
            proxy_number += 1
            sleep(1)
    else:
        if spam_text == None:
            spam_text = input("Write spam text : ")
        for token in userToken:
            p = subprocess.Popen([pythonCommand,'bots/server/discord_text_spam.py',token,spam_text,proxy_list[proxy_number]])
            proxy_number += 1
            sleep(1)

if in_pick == 2:
    for token in userToken:
        p = subprocess.Popen([pythonCommand, 'bots/server/discord_image_spam.py', token,proxy_list[proxy_number]])
        proxy_number += 1

if in_pick == 3:
    for token in userToken:
        p = subprocess.Popen([pythonCommand,'bots/server/discord_insult_spam.py', token,proxy_list[proxy_number]])
        proxy_number += 1

#DM Spammers
if in_pick == 4:
    if os.path.exists('text.txt'):
        if not os.path.exists('dm_spam_text.txt'):
            file = open('dm_spam_text.txt','w')
            file.write('=====Merubokkusu=====\n')#This is written for bug issues :/
            file.close()
        for token in userToken:
            p = subprocess.Popen([pythonCommand,'bots/DM/discord_text_spam_dm.py',token,'null',proxy_list[proxy_number]])
            proxy_number += 1
            sleep(2.5)
    else:
        if not os.path.exists('dm_spam_text.txt'):
            file = open('dm_spam_text.txt','w')
            file.write('=====Merubokkusu=====\n')#This is written for bug issues :/
            file.close()
        if spam_text == None:
            spam_text = input("Write spam text : ")
        for token in userToken:
            p = subprocess.Popen([pythonCommand,'bots/DM/discord_text_spam_dm.py',token,spam_text,proxy_list[proxy_number]])
            proxy_number += 1
            sleep(2.5)

if in_pick == 5:
    if not os.path.exists('dm_spam_image.txt'):
        file = open('dm_spam_image.txt','w')
        file.write('=====Merubokkusu=====\n')#This is written for bug issues :/
        file.close()
    for token in userToken:
        p = subprocess.Popen([pythonCommand, 'bots/DM/discord_image_spam_dm.py', token,proxy_list[proxy_number]])
        proxy_number += 1

if in_pick == 6:
    if not os.path.exists('dm_spam_insult.txt'):
        file = open('dm_spam_insult.txt','w')
        file.write('=====Merubokkusu=====\n')#This is written for bug issues :/
        file.close()
    for token in userToken:
        p = subprocess.Popen([pythonCommand,'bots/DM/discord_insult_spam_dm.py', token,proxy_list[proxy_number]])
        proxy_number += 1

if in_pick == 7:
    for token in userToken:
        if userToken == False:
            enp = token.split(':')
            p = subprocess.Popen([pythonCommand,'bots/misc/joinServer.py',enp[0],enp[1],inviteLink,useBrowser,proxy_list[proxy_number]])
            proxy_number += 1
            sleep(joinSpeed)
        else:
            p = subprocess.Popen([pythonCommand,'bots/misc/joinServer2.0.py',token,inviteLink,proxy_list[proxy_number]])
            proxy_number += 1
            sleep(joinSpeed)

if in_pick == 8:
    if(captchaAPI == ""):
        print("This requires an API key from https://2captch9a.com/")
    else:
        for combo in emailList:
            enp = combo.split(':')
            p = subprocess.Popen([pythonCommand,'bots/misc/account-creator/account_creator.py',enp[0],enp[1],proxy_list[proxy_number]])
            proxy_number += 1
            sleep(joinSpeed)
if in_pick == 9:
    if(captchaAPI == ""):
        print("This requires an API key from https://2captcha.com/")
    else:
        for combo in emailList:
            for tknv in tokenV:
                enp = combo.split(':')
                p = subprocess.Popen([pythonCommand,'bots/misc/account-creator/account_verify.py',enp[0],enp[1],proxy_list[proxy_number],tknv])
                proxy_number += 1
                sleep(joinSpeed)

p.wait()
```

It just says name error for p.wait that p isn't defined (im a noob)
I tried everything and it still will not work! I need this for a bot I am developing and I am trying to do this but I have only this issue so help me out :) (BTW I only get the error when I select 8 or 9)

Comment: Does `p` get defined under every condition? For example, what if `in_pick == 9` and `captchaAPI == ""`?

Comment: it only gives me errors on 8 and 9

Answer (score 0):

It could be because no one of those if statement is satisfied and so p won't be created(Since p is only defined inside of the many if statement). You should define it in the  beginnig of the file and the let, if one of those if statement get triggered, be modified.

Comment: how would i fix it